# A Complex query into Union mysql multiple times - Optimizer

Tags: mysql, optimization, subquery, union

I want to use a same subquery multiple times into UNION. This subquery is time consumed and I think that using it a lot of times may will be increased the total time of execution.

For example

```
(SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM A INNER JOIN B ... AND SOME COMPLEX WHERE CONDITIONS) as T ORDER BY column1 DESC LIMIT 10)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM A INNER JOIN B ... AND SOME COMPLEX WHERE CONDITIONS) as T ORDER BY column2 DESC LIMIT 10)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM A INNER JOIN B ... AND SOME COMPLEX WHERE CONDITIONS) as T ORDER BY column3 DESC LIMIT 10)
```

Does the `(SELECT * FROM A INNER JOIN B ... AND SOME COMPLEX WHERE CONDITIONS)` executed 3 times ?

If mysql is smart enough the internal subquery will be executed only one so I don't need any optimization, but if not I have to use something else to optimize it (like using a temporary table, but I want to avoid it)

Do I have to optimize this query by other syntax ? Any suggestion ?

In practice I want to filter some data from huge records and get some of them in 3 group-sections, each section in different order

Comment: obviusly  is executed 3 times  .. you are using order by   on different column and for obtain the result all the 3 subquery are executed completly

Comment: The subquery is exactly the same! So T alias is the same, in second time I order in different column I have no problem with that. I ask only about the sub-sub query

Comment: The 3 subquery are complety rexecuted  .. the dinamic table is not reused .. for the db engine the 3 query are even 3 new query  ..if you want better performance be sure you have proper index on the column you use for filtering

Comment: So What can I do to avoid the 3 time execution ?

Comment: if you want 3 different  set of  10 rows  based  on different order  ... you can't avoid  the 3 query  ... is SQL  .. is not a magic .. is not possible obatin 3 different things form the same query

Comment: Maybe misunderstanding... Suppose the (SELECT * FROM A INNER JOIN B ... AND SOME COMPLEX WHERE CONDITIONS) as T is a REAL table, in this case the Table needn't recalculated, After of that I can use it as many time I need (yes "order by" recalculated it, but the first table (internal subquery) don't need...). I want to AVOID the subquery recalulation NOT the external orders

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170435/discussion-between-kon-apaz-and-scaisedge).

Comment: if you create the table with  "CREATE TABLE as  select  .. then you have a real table  .. otherwise  .. you have 3 time the same dataset  .. (and is not reused by the query engine)

Comment: In this moment a can't chat ..

Comment: Does a temporary Table help ? CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE T (SELECT * FROM A INNER JOIN B ... AND SOME COMPLEX WHERE CONDITIONS); And then  (SELECT * FROM T ORDER BY column1 DESC LIMIT 10)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM T ORDER BY column2 DESC LIMIT 10)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM T ORDER BY column3 DESC LIMIT 10) ?

Answer (score 1):

Plan A:

A `TEMPORARY TABLE` cannot be referenced more than once.  So, build a permanent table and `DROP` it when finished.  (If you might have multiple connections doing the same thing, it will be a hassle to make sure you are not using the same table name.)

Plan B:

With MySQL 8.0, you can do

```
WITH T AS ( SELECT ... )
SELECT ... FROM T ORDER BY col1
UNION ...
```

Plan C:

If it is possible to do this:

```
SELECT id FROM A
     ORDER BY col1 LIMIT 10
```

You could use that as a 'derived' table inside

```
(SELECT * FROM A INNER JOIN B ... AND SOME COMPLEX WHERE CONDITIONS)
```

Something like

```
SELECT A.*, B.*
    FROM ( SELECT id FROM A
               ORDER BY col1 LIMIT 10 ) AS x1
    JOIN A  USING(id)
    JOIN B ... AND SOME COMPLEX WHERE CONDITIONS
```

Similarly for the other two `SELECTs`, then `UNION` them together.

Better yet, `UNION` together the 3 sets of `ids`, *then* `JOIN` to `A` and `B` *once*.

This *may* have the advantage of dealing with fewer rows.